# AngularDart ng-change

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have html:

```dart
<select ng-model="main.selectedReport" ng-change="main.selectReport()">
                            <option value="">Not selected</option>
                            <option ng-repeat="rep in main.reports" value="{{rep.value1}}">{{rep.value2}}</option>
                        </select>
```

My controller is:

```dart
@NgController(selector: '[main-controller]', publishAs: 'main')
class MainController extends FCViewAbstractController {

  Map reports;
  Long selectedReport;

....

  selectReport() {
    print(selectedReport);
  }
}
```

My question is why do I get previous selected value in selectReport()?
For example: on first selection I got null value.

But version in angularjs works as I expect http://plnkr.co/edit/ILBBWfkRp9tegQZaGZ9u?p=preview

Comment: Have you tried with a controller that doesn't extend another class. It looks like a bug but ng-change is such a simple directive that I wonder  if there are special circumstances that lead to the misbehavior.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes, the same result. I'm wondering too.

Comment: What Angular version are you using?

Comment: Currently I'm using 0.9.7. The same as provided in dart examples with latest Dart SDK.

Comment: I don't know if 0.9.9 works with Dart stable. I think it's worth a try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems to be a known bug
[ng-change for  is invoked before the model is updated #399](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/399)

a workaround:

```dart
  selectReport() {
    new Future(() => print(selectedReport));
  }
```

Comment: only 1 upvote... lol. thanks for the workaround as this is still a problem with latest angular dart version.